# Console.log() misteriously inverts return value of a Regex.test

Tags: javascript, regex, console.log

I just had a big headache because of a console.log() placed inside a function that validates a String using a Phone number Regex.

Code:

```
var phoneIsValid = function(phone){
    var re = /^55[1-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]{7}|55[1-9][0-9]9[0-9]{8}$/g;
    //console.log(re.test(phone))
    return re.test(phone);
};
phoneIsValid('555199997330'); //valid phone, should return true
```

This function is allright, properly validates the string. But if you uncomment the console.log line, it inverts the return value of the function.

Do anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: There's no need for the `g` modifier here, and it's causing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: Yeah, actually i didn't know it was all about the global modifier. Thx.